# cv2.imshow() function isn't displaying anything when I call it

Tags: python, opencv

I'm following one of the openCV python tutorials on displaying a live video feed from your camera. When I run the program, the green light for the webcam comes on (as I'm on a Mac) and there aren't any errors. Theres also a python rocketship thing that comes up in my dock, but it doesn't show any windows or anything. This also happens when I try and display one image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the code I'm using. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you running inside some IDE? Try saving your Python script as a file and just running it from the command-line in Terminal.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I was running the program in pycharm, and I've tried it in terminal now, but the same thing is happening

Comment: please check ret returning True or False

Comment: Ok, please add `print(frame.shape)` after `cap.read()`. That will tell us a) if your main loop js actually running at all and b) if you are actually reading any frames.

Comment: Maybe its because of a dependency. Try installing ```tkinter```. And maybe even matplotlib and pillow etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `cv.named Window command` to open a new window :

```
cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
cv2.WaitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I hope this works well with you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [here](https://txt.arboreus.com/2012/07/11/highgui-opencv-window-from-ipython.html). Try adding below line on top.

```py
import cv2.
cv2.startWindowThread()
```

And inside for loop run this.

```py
cv2.namedWindow("frame")
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using conda interpreter on my mac through visual studio code. Changing the interpreter made it work.
One more thing you can try is changing the version of python interpreter, because I downgraded from using 3.10.xx to 3.9.xx and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer might work for you but is in general not the issue @The all time cow Tomlinson has. In fact his code runs fine on a windows 10 installation with a fresh install in a virtual environment with only `opeencv-python` installed in a python 3.10.7 installation.